# Worth using getters and setters in DTOs? (C++)

Tags: c++, client-server, business-objects, dto

I have to write a bunch of DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) - their sole purpose is to transfer data between client app(s) and the server app, so they have a bunch of properties, a serialize function and a deserialize function.

When I've seen DTOs they often have getters and setters, but is their any point for these types of class?  I did wonder if I'd ever put validation or do calculations in the methods, but I'm thinking probably not as that seems to go beyond the scope of their purpose.

At the server end, the business layer deals with logic, and in the client the DTOs will just be used in view models (and to send data to the server).

Assuming I'm going about all of this correctly, what do people think?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** AND if so, would their be any issue with putting the get / set implementation in the class definition?  Saves repeating everything in the cpp file...

Comment: I was sure you were talking about C# here. Out of curiosity, how do you serialize your C++ classes?

Comment: What do your objects look like in code?

Comment: @Daniel: When serialize is called each property is appended in their binary form into a passed in growable data buffer (pretty much a binary copy for ints for instance).  Simple stuff really - I also encode a small header in front of each property to allow missing/unexpected data to be deserialized without causing a problem (perhaps because of a different version of the DTO being serialized at other end).  It all works fine and I've used it in several projects.  I may add an XML mechanism to it to allow objects to go to and from 3rd party software more easily (though with far less efficiency).

Comment: @Larsmans: I've only got my old objects that worked differently.  This is a new idea I'm exploring, so there's no code yet.  I'm not sure what you'd be looking for, but basically there'd be the usual destructor/constructor, probably serialize/deserialize functions, and a load of setters/getters (or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a class whose explicit purpose is just to store it's member variables in one place, you may as well just make them all public.

Comment: Second that, sounds like a job for plain old `struct`.

Comment: A lot of the DTO examples on here seem to have getters and setters but I think they are all C# examples where it's a lot easier to define properties (from what I can see).  Tending to agree though regarding plain old struct, though the serialization methods would still be there so not quiet just a struct unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The object would likely not require destructor (you only need a destructor if you need to cleanup resources, e.g. pointers, but if you're serializing a pointer, you're just asking for trouble). It's probably nice to have some syntax sugars constructors, but nothing really necessary.

If the data is just a Plain Old Data (POD) object for carrying data, then it's a candidate for being a struct (fully public class).

However, depending on your design, you might want to consider adding some behavior, e.g. an .action() method, that knows how to integrate the data it is carrying to your actual Model object; as opposed to having the actual Model integrating those changes itself. In effect, the DTO can be considered part of the Controller (input) instead of part of Model (data).

In any case, in any language, a getter/setter is a sign of poor encapsulation. It is not OOP to have a getter/setter for each instance fields. [Objects should be Rich, not Anemic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_Domain_Model). If you really want an Anemic Object, then skip the getter/setter and go directly to POD full-public struct; there is almost no benefit of using getter/setter over fully public struct, except that it complicates code so it might give you a higher rating if your workplace uses lines of code as a productivity metric.

Comment: Agree regarding rich objects, however I'm thinking DTOs are a special case.  The only other way I can think of doing it is having the application specific rich objects at either end of the physical separation have the properties and serialize/deserialize methods that the DTO would have, but this IMHO would complicate matters purely to avoid having a common class that can be used easily at each end.  Surely better that the DTO becomes a property of the rich object instead?

Comment: I suppose it's almost like the DTO is a partial class that becomes whole within each app when augmented with a rich class.  Sorry thinking out loud, could be nonesense ;-)

Comment: @Mark: I think there is two equally good solution 1) is having a rich DTO with *rich* methods, e.g. .send(), .serialize(), .deserialize(), .apply(), etc 2) public struct DTO, possibly with a few *rich* methods (.serialize) and complemented with a rich wrapper (.send). The first is simpler, the second allows multiple wrappers sharing the same DTO or multiple DTO sharing the same wrapper. What I'm advocating against is for having a public setter and getter for each private instance fields, that's overcomplicating the code for zero gain.